# Difference between setAndAllowWhileIdle and setExactAndAllowWhileIdle

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-alarms, android-doze-and-standby

What is difference between `AlarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle()` and `AlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`? How does these both affect Doze mode introduced in Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the documentation of `AlarmManager`:

> **Note:** Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

Indeed, both the methods you mentioned specify that they behave like their counterparts without the "AndAllowWhileIdle" (`set` and `setExact`). So one of them will deliver the alarm at the exact time and the other will not be exact.

Comment: What is effect of Marshmallow doze on these APIs?

Comment: @Malwinder presumably the "AndAllowWhileIdle" ones will still be delivered if the device is dozing.